# Celery raises ValueError: not enough values to unpack

Tags: python, celery

Trying to run simple example with Celery and receiving an exception. RabbitMQ started in a Docker, also tried to start it locally. Celery works on a local Windows host

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://192.168.99.100:32774')

@app.task()
def hello():
    print('hello')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello.delay()
```

Excerpt of my error text:

```
[2017-08-18 00:01:08,632: ERROR/MainProcess] Task handler raised error: ValueError('not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)',)
Traceback (most recent call last):                                              
    File "c:\users\user\celenv\lib\site-packages\billiard\pool.py", line 358, in workloop                        
        result = (True, prepare_result(fun(*args, **kwargs)))                                  
    File "c:\users\user\celenv\lib\site-packages\celery\app\trace.py", line 525, in _fast_trace_task
        tasks, accept, hostname = _loc
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)
```

Comment: which celery version? as far as I remember celery doesn't supported in windows since celery 4

Comment: @ItayB Thank you! I've found that the problem exactly in celery on windows, but I didn't know this about version 4. I've used 4.1.0.

Comment: add it as answer, you can vote/accept please

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Which celery version? As far as I remember celery isn't supported in windows since celery 4

Answer (score 99):

`Celery 4.0+` does not officially support Windows yet. But it still works on Windows for some development/test purposes.

Use `eventlet` instead as below:

```
pip install eventlet
celery -A <module> worker -l info -P eventlet
```

It works for me on `Windows 10` + `celery 4.1` + `python 3`.

===== update 2018-11 =====

Eventlet has an issue on subprocess.CalledProcessError:

https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4063

https://github.com/eventlet/eventlet/issues/357

https://github.com/eventlet/eventlet/issues/413

So try `gevent` instead.

```
pip install gevent
celery -A <module> worker -l info -P gevent
```

This works for me on `Windows 10` + `celery 4.2` + `python 3.6`

Comment: I tried running with `-l info -c 5 gevent` flags and got `unrecognized arguments: gevent`.
It however works with `-l info -P gevent`.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 21):

It worked for me:

```
celery -A my_project_name worker --pool=solo -l info
```

basically things become single threaded and are suppoted

Comment: It's still working in Nov 29th, 2022. Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

I got this error on Windows 7 32bit system. So I did this to make it work.

Add this

```
`os.environ.setdefault('FORKED_BY_MULTIPROCESSING', '1')`
```

before defining a celery instance in `myproj/settings.py` file in your django project.

It should like like

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproj.settings')
os.environ.setdefault('FORKED_BY_MULTIPROCESSING', '1')

app = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0')
```

I am using redis as a messaging broker so defined `broker='redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0'`

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me.  Would have spent hours (on top of the ones already spent).  I was just trying the example from docs.celeryproject.org: 
import os  
os.environ.setdefault('FORKED_BY_MULTIPROCESSING', '1')

app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

etc

Answer (score 12):

For `Celery 4.1` on Windows.

Set an environment variable `FORKED_BY_MULTIPROCESSING=1`. Then you can simply run `celery -A <celery module> worker`.

Answer (score 0):

run this command

celery -A name_of_project worker --pool=solo -l info