# Clarification required django celery,celery and djangoceleryemail compatabilty versions to handle asynchronous tasks

Tags: django-celery

I am new to Django.

I am developing one django application which needs following packages to handle asynchronous tasks in the back ground.

1.djangocelery
2.djangocelery email.

App definitions in My settings.py file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'crispy_forms',
    'djcelery',
    'gspapp',
    'djcelery_email',
    #'django_celery_results',
]
```

But when i install these packages in my virtual environment, I encountered with the below errors:

1.I have django-celery - 3.3.1 and celery 4.3.0 initially.
2.when i execute the celery worker command :celery -A gspaat worker --loglevel=info

## i got the below error:

## ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kombu.asynchronous'

As per the message posted in below link,i uninstalled celery version and installed latest celery version 4.3.0 . 
[Cannot start Celery Worker (Kombu.asynchronous.timer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50511905/cannot-start-celery-worker-kombu-asynchronous-timer)

## But unfortunately i am facing with below error.

ERROR: django-celery 3.3.1 has requirement celery<4.0,>=3.1.15, but you'll have celery 4.3.0 which is incompatible.
Due to above error, i installed celery version :3.1.25 using pip install celery==3.1.25 but i got the below error

## ERROR: django-celery-email 2.0.2 has requirement celery>=4.0, but you'll have celery 3.1.25 which is incompatible.

So, please share the compatible version of djcelery , celery and djcelery_email.

Regards,
N.Dilip Kumar.

Comment: I am facing the same situation. Have you found anything !

Comment: No need to install separately djcelery to integrate celery with django since 3.1.You can refer https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#configuring-your-django-project-to-use-celery for more details.